# Filesystem problem

Tags: linux, disk

I have a server on Hetzner. It theoretically has 3Tb of space

But if I run df -h I see this:

```
Filesystem           Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                 7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev
213.133.99.101:/nfs  295G  134G  146G  48% /root/.oldroot/nfs
overlay              7.7G  7.7G     0 100% /
tmpfs                7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                7.7G   20M  7.7G   1% /run
tmpfs                5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                7.7G     0  7.7G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/0
```

So, the 3TB are missing. ...And the disk is full.

If I run lsblk I see this:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0    4G  1 loop
sda      8:0    0  2.7T  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0    8G  0 part
├─sda2   8:2    0  512M  0 part
├─sda3   8:3    0    1T  0 part
├─sda4   8:4    0  1.7T  0 part
└─sda5   8:5    0    1M  0 part
```

Seems the 3Tb are out there.

How can I use them?

PS. Yes, I am not a linux expert..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks to me like you are currently running the "delivery system". 
You should be able to start an installer from there, and set up your system as you need it. Search the hetzner knowledge-base for infos on installer images.

When installing from such an installer, keep in mind:

- Hetzner-servers in general come with two identical harddisk to be able to set up a raid1-array. This should be done for safety of your data.
- as you cannot see a second physical disk, you may consider asking hetzner about it
- when you install a fresh system, you can safely delete all partitions, so the space will be available for you.
- as a recommendation, reserve some space (create partitions) for

  - boot (1-2 Ggb)
  - /  (around 30Gb)
  - swap (2 times ram-size)
  - /home (rest)
- you need to setup the raid1 (if you do) *before* installing the system. you would then mount '/dev/mdX' instead of '/dev/sdX'

Answer (score 1):

Putting the trivial question first: is the 3Tb disk formatted and mounted? `df` only shows information on filesystems that are actually mounted.

If you have little experience in Linux file system administration, then the following links may provide useful information:

- https://www.linuxsysadmins.com/create-and-mount-filesystems-in-linux/
- https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-create-and-mount-filesystems-in-linux/

You may not need to create a filesystem, try mounting the partition first to see if there is one already. You can also check the presence of a filesystem on, say, `/dev/sda1` by running (as root)

```
udevadm info /dev/sda1 | grep "ID_FS_TYPE"
```

If the partition is already formatted with a file system, it will print one line with the filesystem type (`vfat`, `ntfs`, ...). If it is not yet formatted, the command will produce no output.

Comment: Well, it's a bit dangerous to send him directly on a mkfs answer...

Comment: @darxmurf Yes, I actually wanted to point him to the _question_ so that he can use the links provided in the answers, but I still had my answer in the URL bar. I changed it.

Answer (score 0):

As AdminBee said, it's not because a disk is plugged in your linux will display it.

To use an existing and formatted partition, you have to mount it. From your root account, type

```
mount /dev/sdaX /mnt/
```

where X is the number of the partition you want to mount and /mnt/ the destination folder. IE

```
mount /dev/sda4 /mnt/
```

will mount your 1.7Tb partition in the /mnt/ folder

If your partition is not formatted, then yes you have to create a file system on it before mount.

Comment: If I execute mount /dev/sda /mnt/ I get the following error: "mount: /mnt: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sda, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.". If I run mount /dev/sda4 /mnt/ I don't get any error (does it mean that I have to mount all the 5 sdas?). However the df command still does not show any added space

Comment: Your first command tried to mount the disk per se; this isn't possible. You have to mount the partitions individually to use them. If you didn't get any error from mounting `/dev/sda4`, this means the mount succeeded. Try changing to the directory `/mnt` and take a look via `ls` (e.g.). If you want to use that drive regularly, you will want to create mount-points for each partition and also add it to your `/etc/fstab`. I will provide the links I mentioned in my answer directly, you may want to take a look at the tutorials provided there.

Comment: still from root, you can also run "parted /dev/sda list" and paste that here to see disk info

Comment: This command gives a lot of lines, but any of them contains ID_FS_TYPE. If I run mke2fs /dev/sda4 I get the error: /dev/sda4 is mounted; will not make a filesystem here!

Comment: See my updated comment. If the mount succeeded, you have a working filesystem already and don't need to create one via `mkfs`.

Comment: The command "ls /mnt" shows a folder called "lost+found". What is this folder? Anyway, does it mean the partition is usable and no format is required? I have tried to edit the file /etc/fstab adding there the lines shown by the command "blkid" (is this correct?) but it seems I cannot edit this file, an "error writing file" message appears

Comment: No offense mate, but you should probably read up on what these commands actually mean before executing them. There's a high chance of losing data/creating more issues.

Comment: lost+found is a default folder created in case of file system error/corruption. By the way, once you mounted your file system in /mnt/ you should see it then with the df command. If yes, it means you can use it.